# caret: RFE with tuneLength and rerank

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

When using rfe() with tuneLength set and rerank = TRUE, is the parameter in tuneLength optimized when rankings are recalculated on the subset of features?
Here is an exmple of the analysis I am doing:

```
library("caret")
set.seed(342)
train <- as.data.frame ( matrix( rnorm(1e4) , 100, 100 ) )

ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs,        
               rerank = TRUE,
               method = "repeatedcv",
               number=2, 
               repeats=1,
               verbose =TRUE
)

pls.fit.rfe <- rfe(V1 ~ .,
               data = train,   
               method = "pls",                    
               sizes =  c(2,5),
               tuneLength = 5, 
               rfeControl = ctrl
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The re-ranking happens after the each PLS fit. I don't think that the rankings have any direct impact on the model tuning.

Max

Comment: yes, I read [link](http://topepo.github.io/caret/rfe.html). But the rankings will depend on the choice for the parameter in the 1:tuneLength (ncomp in my example). So is there a cross-validated optimization of ncomps when the rerank is computed?